# Rails has_one with polymorphic comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an issue getting the last comment of an item, in this specific case I need the last comment on the Topic model. Because comments are polymorphic, I get incorrect results when I use the :commentable_id as the foreign key.

```
has_one :latest_comment, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :commentable_id
```

This is because, for example, if my Topic id is 7 and someone later makes a comment on a Track that has the id of 7, Rails shows the information for that Track comment as being the latest comment.

The portion of my view as I loop through the topics:

```
<% if topic.comments.any? %>
    last reply by <%= link_to topic.latest_comment.user.username, user_path(topic.latest_comment.user) %>
<% else %>
    by <%= link_to topic.user.username, user_path(topic.user_id) %>
<% end %>
```

How can I include something like a where statement in the model so it also grabs the commentable_type == "topic" in addition to the :commentable_id foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_one :latest_comment, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :commentable_id
```

Add `where(commentable_type: 'Topic')` to your existing line above:

```
has_one :latest_comment, -> { where(commentable_type: 'Topic').order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :commentable_id
```

**Update:**

With `:as` option in `has_one` as mentioned here https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one, you can also do:

```
has_one :latest_comment, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, as: :commentable
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the thing I needed.